# MS Access VBA - Form.Filter

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am wrestling with a task to filter a form based on a word. `Text1` is my filter or search word. I want to search Text1 under `myTable.Name`.

It crushes every time. I appreciate any help.

```
Private Sub Text1_AfterUpdate()
Dim strChange As String, strSQL As String, strBuilding As String

If IsNull(Me.Text1) Then
     Me!sfm.Form.FilterOn = False
Else
     Debug.Print Me.Text1

     Me!sfm.Form.Filter = "mytable.Name like '*" & Me!Text1 & "*'"
     Me!sfm.Form.FilterOn = True
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Name is a reserved word. have you tried `[mytable].[Name]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Field` name directly without table name like

```
Me!sfm.Form.Filter = "[Field_Name] LIKE '*" & Me!Text1 & "*'"
```

Here `Field_Name` is your control name at Subform.

Comment: it doesn't work, it opens up a small window and asks for a parameter.

Comment: Then use `Field_Name LIKE`. What is your `Control` name at subform?

Comment: I have a main form and the form uses the data from 3 tables. What you mean with control? I used the same code for another table and it worked.

Comment: @Harun24HR: A filter is a "where clause" and usually does not contain conditions for controls but for fields.

Comment: @WolfgangKais Yes. Thats correct. Sometimes user keep `FiledName` and `Control` name same. I will be more careful in future. Thanks for catching.

Answer (score 0):

If *Name* is the field name, it should read:

```
Me!sfm.Form.Filter = "[Name] like '*" & Me!Text1 & "*'"
```

And do rename your controls (*Text1*) to something meaningful - like *SearchText*.

Comment: it opens a small windows and asks for a parameter. When I close this windows, I get runtime 2101 error. The same code worked for another table.

Comment: This error indicates a _missing_ or _misspelled_ field name.

Answer (score 0):

I search the control element in my form, found one. It wasn't my table. So I changed [Name] with [ControlElement] and it worked. Thank you very much.

Comment: Please consider [accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if you find that it solved your problem and/or upvote helpful answers.